# Create 3D outline text, Error when imporing gltf

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, import

I created transparent, yellow outlined 3d text using spline, but when I import file and put it on website, it shows just white text without outline, can you guys help me creating this simple 3d text on Blender? [image]

Comment: Sorry, your question lacks a lot of information. How did you create the transparent yellow outlined text? How did you export it? Where/how did you try to embed it in a website?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures